# In ggplot when all values are TRUE the fill colour is red, how to change that?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Code example is quite simple:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = mpg < 34) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

You get this: [image: Wrong factor colours]

But when you have at least some false samples:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = mpg < 20) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

THEN, the colours are correct. [image]
Am I missing something, or is that an inconsistent behaviour and...anybody can help get the correct blue when all is TRUE?

Comment: Add `scale_fill_discrete(limits = c('TRUE', 'FALSE'))`. I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, I'll try to find it.

Comment: A discrete color scale uses a palette of discrete colors. It depicts category (factor) variables. The first color in the palette is used for the first factor level, the second for the second, ... If you rely on automatic coercion to factor as in your examples, the factor levels are ordered alphabetically.

Comment: @Axeman You can try the example, it's quite easy to test...if I add  scale_fill_discrete(limits = c('TRUE', 'FALSE')) it's still all red here...

Comment: @Axeman `FALSE` and `TRUE` should be reversed. Apart from that, I got curious too. Is there any way except manually defining the color and except having two factors in the legend to force using the same color for `TRUE/FALSE` factors?

Comment: Sorry just put them in the required order: `c(FALSE, TRUE)`

Comment: @Roland so how would you reorder the palette, so that when there's TRUE & FALSE values, TRUE is blue, and when there's only TRUE values, TRUE is still blue.

Comment: You need to either force having both TRUE and FALSE as factor levels and requiring `drop = FALSE`, or you need to set the scale limits manually.

Comment: @Masoud Thank you! I'll have to go read about that 'limits' argument for scale_fill

Comment: @Axeman understood, thank you.

Comment: you can check out `?scale_fill_manual`, which gives an example, where you pass in a named vector of the colors. So you can specify your color choices like this `cols <- c("TRUE" = "blue", "FALSE" = "red")

ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, fill = mpg < 34) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
`